# How can I use mod rewrite to point to a subdirectory given a subdomain?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I had this almost working several hours ago, but I can't seem to get all the mod-rewrite stuff working right for Zend.

Given this directory structure:

```
/home/branches/branch1/public/index.php
/home/branches/branch2/public/index.php
/home/branches/branch3/public/index.php
```

How can I access these like so:

```
branch1.branch.example.com
branch2.branch.example.com
branch3.branch.example.com
```

Without having to hardcode in each branch?

Here's my starting point ([source](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/08/20/redirecting-subdomains-to-directories-in-apache/)), (I somehow can't even get this to work at the moment, but I swear it was working this morning, ha!).

```
ServerAlias *.branch.example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.branch\.example\.com
RewriteCond /home/branches/%1/public
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

(Side note: I'm actually working with a huge codebase using old alpha version of ZF that uses /www/errors.php as a bootstrap instead of /public/index.php, (and might even need some different rewrite rules than the current version) but I modified the above code to fit the current ZF setup)

Comment: Does the solution here **have** to be mod_rewrite? Do you have access to the Apache config? Can you use [Apache Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)?

Comment: @Leigh: Virtual Hosts sounds like the right idea, but do you know if it can handle the wildcard branch names? (I don't mean the routing aspect here.)

Comment: @Kevin Ah, now that I think about it, I guess we're talking about on-the-fly sub-domain creation based on whatever content happens to be there (i.e. branch4 can be created without an Apache restart), opposed to statically hosted sub-domains. In which case rewriting seems like the better option.

Comment: Yes! I want to branch the trunk, then BAM! No additional config required! Start writing code! (Also, I have access to everything. This is a dedicated, on-site host, no restrictions, plenty of resourses)

Comment: Ok, we can probably help.  Have you tried the answer I gave?  Leave a comment there if you discover a hitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured a wildcard subdomain (for routing purposes)?  It won't work unless you do.

I also think this line won't work:

```
RewriteCond /home/branches/%1/public
```

I think that your last line needs to be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/branches/%1/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm.. that makes it *look* like it should be working, but now I'm getting a 500 error because it loops like this: (/test/www/index.html exists, not sure why it's skipping past it?)
redirected from r->uri = /test/www/test/www/
redirected from r->uri = /test/www/
redirected from r->uri = /

Comment: Also, I'm actually just doing this in my htconfig:

ServerName *.branch.example.com